# onActivityReenter is not called in parent activity after returning from 3rd activity

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have 3 activities: Main, B, C

My Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.one.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".B"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".C"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
```

I start activity B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.  
                   makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                        imageView,
                        ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageView));
ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(this, intent, 666, options.toBundle());
```

Shared element transition works fine, then I start activity C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.  
                   makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                        imageView,
                        ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageView));
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, options.toBundle());
```

Shared element transition also works fine, then I want to return to parent MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
setResult(666);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.  
                   makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                        imageView,
                        ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageView));
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, options.toBundle());
```

Here I have a problem: onActivityReenter is not called, Shared element transition not working:

I Also tried this for returning to MainActivity:

```
setResult(666);
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

But having the same result: default transition applied.
Any ideas how to make transition working?

Comment: any solution for this please, facing same problem